# How to display EFI volume in Explorer?

Tags: cmd.exe, mount, efi

I'm still stuck at an error message.

[image]

Comment: what exactly is the error message? Windows 10 probably has 4 volumes. Try diskmgmt.msc from the command prompt.

Comment: And why do you want to display the ESP in Explorer? That's always a very bad idea.

Comment: I second @GabrielaGarcia's sentiment, however it can be mounted via `diskpart`

Comment: What command did you run that returns this error?

Comment: That screenshot says that your EFI partition is mounted at G:\ ... Is that not true? Can you see the partition on drive G?

Answer (score 1):

Mounting the EFI partition is a bad idea, unless you need to modify a file within it, which you shouldn't, but it can be mounted via `DiskPart`

1. **<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** > *Open:* `diskpart` > OK

   1. List drives: `lis dis`
   2. Select OS drive: `sel dis #`
   3. List partitions: `lis par`
   4. Select EFI partition: `sel par #`
   5. Assign mount letter [`Z:\`]: `assign letter=z`
   6. Remove mount letter: `remove`

      - *Assumes EFI partition is still the selected partition, but if it's not, repeat 1.1 - 1.4*